# VBA: Unicode to ASCII conversion?

Tags: vba, unicode, ascii

I have a string that is in unicode format that I want to convert to ASCII format.  If the character is not in the ASCII range, then it should be converted to the closest English letter. For example "Ǎǎǵǩȥȑȍ" to "Aagkzro".

Comment: You have not asked a question.  Please rephrase and state clearly what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, what errors you get, and anything else that will be helpful for us.

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search pulled up [the following link](http://blog.brettski.com/2009/12/04/vba-convert-unicode-to-ascii/) which partially works for you example.

However, there are codes (ǵ) which will just return a question mark.  In these cases, you will want to check for that value specifically and convert it to what you're expecting.